# Add an ID to control display order

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a webpart that displays links. The wp links to a SP list. I added and ID column to the list and added the display order (1,2,3 and so on)...
The problem is that the links aren't displayed in the order I want them. Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  queryListDataNewsCardBig();
});

function queryListDataNewsCardBig() {
  var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
  $.ajax({
    url:
      siteurl +
      "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Services')/items?$select=LinkToArticle,ID,MekorotDepartments/Title,Title&$Expand=MekorotDepartments",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.d !== undefined) {
        console.log(data.d);
        var item = data.d;
        var html = "";
        $(data.d.results).each(function (i) {
          html +=
            "" +
            '<div class="news-card-info">' +
            '<a href="' +
            this.LinkToArticle.Url +
            '" class="service-wrap">' +
            " <h1>" +
            this.Title +
            '<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>' +
            "</h1>" +
            "</a>" +
            ' <div class="department-wrap">' +
            '<span class="bold">' +
            "from:" +
            "</span>" +
            '<a href="#" class="icon-link">' +
            this.MekorotDepartments.Title +
            "</a>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>";
        });

        $(".news-card-wrap").html(html);
      }
    },
    error: function (data) {
      alert("Error: " + data);
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$orderby` query option to specify how to sort the items in your query return set.

```
"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Services')/items?$select=LinkToArticle,ID,MekorotDepartments/Title,Title&$Expand=MekorotDepartments&$orderby=ID asc",
```

[Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests-Sort returned items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#sort-returned-items)

Comment: If my reply helps you, you could accept it as the answer.